# What can I do to make a multi-option, dual-choice selection dialog

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, radio-button, objectdatasource

The question title doesn't do the best job describing what I need. This question essentially relates to radio buttons in a list. There will be a variable number of choices. Each choice will have two radio buttons, indicating a first order or second order. But no matter how many choices there are, the user can only put two of them in order. Here is a picture I drafted up that might help.

[image: If you see this, the image didn't load.]

It's being done in a modal, but everything else can change. Perhaps a Grid View would be better? The data comes from Object Data Sources. When the user hits Submit, I will update my database to record the user's preference. For example, the user wants Choice A in Position 1 and Choice D in Position 2, all other choices are irrelevant.

Any help would be appreciated. Definitely wanted to start here first before wasting hours and ending up with inefficient code and senseless design, lol. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Greg. What is your question, how to design this selection dialog in best way or if it can be done like in your picture?

Comment: @chrillelundmark, honestly both. It is already designed and coded, but I'm having trouble getting the radio buttons to work properly. The logic behind that is tough, it seems. So far, I have the left column of radio buttons in a group and the right column in another group. Problem is, that allows for one of the choices to have two selections, which should not be possible. I need to code it so that radio button selections are exclusive horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Hi again Greg. What if you disable the item in list 2 from code behind after you selected the first one? That shouldn't be hard to do from the first radiobuttonlist's index changed event. Do you need code example?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here I will give a go for a complete answer...

Personally I would disable the second radiobuttonlist (vertically) and enable it after user makes his first choice. If you do that you make logic a little bit easier because now you only have to monitor the user's first choice, not both his first and second choice.

After the user's first selection you will trigger the radiobuttonlist index change event. In that method I would disable the corresponding radiobutton that the user selected in the first selection.

```
protected void FirstRadioButtonList_IndexChanged(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = radioButtonList1.SelectedValue;

    foreach(ListItem item in RadioButtonList2)
    {
        if(item.Value == selectedValue)
        {
            item.Enabled = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this more or less should do it or at least point you in correct direction.